# Отменить открытие клавиатуры в инпутах смартфона

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Всем привет,

Использую bootstrap datepicker и можно ли сделать такб чтобы на полях даты не открывалась клавиатура при клике на этом поле?
Нашел такую https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/494 ссылку

Скачал файл bootstrap-datepicker.js - он втрое больше файла что я пользовал и имеет заголовок

> - bootstrap-datepicker.js  * Repo:
>     https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/  * Demo:
>     http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/  * Docs:
>     http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/  * Forked from
>     http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker

Но выбор даты вообще перестал работать ?

У меня :

> Bootstrap 3 is enabled. Version : 3.3.6. jquery version : 1.11.1 
>   jquery ui version : 1.11.1

У Вас этот дата пикер работает и если да то с какими версиями Bootstrap/jquery ?
Удалсь кому рещить проблему с открытием клавиатуры в инпутах смартфона?

```
 Спасибо!
```

Answer (score 4):

С полями дат js-библиотеки работают двумя способами:

- Оставляют поле даты html5-date полем. Такое поле на мобильном телефоне откроет специальную "клавиатуру" для выбора даты (год/месяц/число тремя барабанами);
- Меняют тип поля на html5-text и привязывают к его фокусу вывод нестандартного календаря. Такое поле на мобильном телефоне вместе с календарем неизбежно откроет стандартную клавиатуру телефона.

За 3 года в веб-разработке я проверил около 10-20 различных датапикеров и календарей, и остановился на [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/). Рекомендую вам перейти на нее.

Pickadate работает по второму принципу - она показывает нестандартный календарь при клике на поле. Но в отличие от других библиотек - она препятствует открытию стандартной клавиатуры на мобильном устройстве. В итоге на телефоне результат будет таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, интересная либа и возник вопрос:
Я задаю с разными форматами отображения и сабмита

$('#filter_created_at_from').pickadate( {  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd', format: 'd mmmm, yyyy', hiddenName: false } )       // http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/
$('#filter_created_at_till').pickadate( {  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd', format: 'd mmmm, yyyy', hiddenName: false   } )

Но я форму не сабмичу, а передаю через ajax и считывая значения поля

```
$("#filter_created_at_till").val()
```

получаю значение в виде `27 August, 2016`
А как получить значение в формате сабмита ?